# When calculate C# solution code coverage, how to include projects not covered by test at all?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, code-coverage, coverlet

I'm using C# to develop a software which contains multiple projects in a Visual Studio solution, and I'm begin adding some unit tests.

Solution hierarchy as below, 3 projects for production code, 2 projects which only tests `Project1` and `Project2`, respectively:

```
Solution
  |
  |- Project1 (100 lines)
  |- Project2 (100 lines)
  |- Project3 (100 lines)
  |
  |- Project1.UnitTests
  |- Project2.UnitTests
```

I followed the [tutorial from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=windows), try to get a total code coverage number of my solution and out as a text file:

```
dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --tool-path tools
dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
reportgenerator "-reports:./**/coverage.cobertura.xml" "-targetdir:Reports_Coverage" -reportTypes:TextSummary;
```

There was coverage in the text file, however the calculation did not put Project3 in to the formula:

- Given that Project1, Project2, Project3 has 100 lines each, Project1, Project2 100% covered by test, Project3 is 0% (no tests)
- The Total coverage that ReportGenerator gave me was 100% (because Project1 and Project2 both 100% covered)
- But what I'm expecting is 67% of coverage (with Project3 in the formula)

How can I get code coverage which includes rojects that has no test covered at all?

Thanks.

Comment: If code isn't tested, it has zero test coverage. Unless you're talking about something else, in which case you should clarify your question.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I've update the question to clarify my intent, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not writing tests for project # 3?

Comment: is project3 referenced in any of the test projects or project1 or project2 ?

Comment: @CodingMytra Well, no. This is a standalone project. Will project3referenced by project1 or project2 make project3 included in the coverage calculation? Thanks for comment.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield The owner is not writing any test (for some reason, at the moment), and I would like to reflect this fact in the coverage report. Thanks for comment.

Comment: @YuWea, it needs to be referenced then only it will be counted for coverage.